# Unexpected/extra rows in Parse.com when using saveEventually

Tags: parse-platform, offline

The following simple example creates three PFObjects and calls saveEventually once for each of them.  The first object is a Parent and the other two are Children.  The Children point tot he Parent.

```
PFObject *a = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Parent"];
[a setObject:@"Test" forKey:@"Test"];
[a saveEventually];

PFObject *b = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Child"];
[b setObject:a forKey:@"parent"];
[b saveEventually];

PFObject *c = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Child"];
[c setObject:a forKey:@"parent"];
[c saveEventually];
```

After this runs, I expect to see:

- One row in Parent with a "Test" value in the Test column.
- Two rows in Child each with a pointer to the Parent row in the parent column.

Instead, I see:

- One row in Parent with "Test" value in the Test column. (expected)
- One row in Parent with "(undefined)" value in the Test column. (unexpected)
- Two rows in Child each with a pointer to the expected Parent row. (expected)

If the example is generalized to N children, it seems that there is always:

- One row in Parent with "Test" value in the Test column. (expected)
- N-1 rows in Parent with "(undefined)" value in the Test column. (unexpected)
- N rows in Child each with a pointer to the expected Parent row. (expected)

All observations were made using Parse's Data Browser.  If it weren't for the unexpected Parent rows, everything would be good.  Any idea what's going on here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to Parse (Héctor Ramos), you should not use saveEventually when nesting objects.

See [this post on the Parse help forum](https://parse.com/questions/simple-saveeventually-example-produces-4-rows-instead-of-3-any-idea-why):

> saveEventually is not a good fit when multiple unsaved objects with
>   relations are being saved simultaneously. Have you tried
>   saveInBackground?

I have the same behavior as you. It *almost* works but you wind up with a lot of extra entries in the table. Sucks :(

Comment: Glad to hear that somebody else is seeing this and that it's not just a figment of my imagination.  Unfortunately, Brian Klimt (also of Parse) seems to say that everything ought to work fine in [this post in the same forum](https://parse.com/questions/how-does-allow-saveeventually-of-objects-with-relations-to-other-new-unsaved-objects-work).